# Schematron sh script not behaving

Tags: xml, shell, xslt-1.0, schematron, docbook-5

I found a shell script for Schematron that your supposed to be able to feed a Schematron schema, and an XML document, so as to apply the Schematron rules to the XML document. I found the script here:

https://code.google.com/p/schematron/wiki/RunningSchematronWithGNOMExsltproc

The various xsl files used by the script are downloaded from the Schematron distribution here:

http://www.schematron.com/implementation.html

I'll repeat the shell script here, for convenience.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Step1 ...
xsltproc iso_dsdl_include.xsl $1 > step1.xsl

echo Step2 ...
xsltproc iso_abstract_expand.xsl step1.xsl > step2.xsl

echo Step3 ...
xsltproc iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl step2.xsl > step3.xsl

echo Validation ...
xsltproc step3.xsl $2 > result.svrl
```

I run the script like this:

run_schematron.sh docbook1.sch my_xml.xml

The shell script generates intermediate files, step1.xsl, step2.xsl, and step3.xsl. But I am already off the rails at step2.xsl, since it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

        @linkend on footnoteref must point to a footnote.

         @linkend on synopfragmentref must point to a synopfragment.
```

That's not looking like an XSL stylesheet to me. Any ideas?

Comment: add a tag for `xml`. YOu have picked all the low-follower count variants. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using [docbook.sch](http://www.docbook.org/xml/5.0/sch/docbook.sch) for DocBook 5.0, which is not an [**ISO Schematron**](http://www.schematron.com/spec.html) schema (the namespace bound to the `s:` prefix is not `http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron`).

In docbook.sch for DocBook 5.0, simply change this:

```
xmlns:s="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron"
```

to this:

```
xmlns:s="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
```

...and it will work.

In [docbook.sch](http://www.docbook.org/xml/5.1CR1/sch/docbook.sch) for DocBook 5.1 (which hasn't been offically released yet), the namespace has been changed.

Comment: Thanks! I'm definitely getting meaningful looking output at each stage of the pipeline now. Although I'm still scratching my head over the contents of result.svrl. But definitely progress.